# Magento update GST value from 10.0000% to 10% on sales invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, pdf

I've been trying to update this GST value from 10.0000% to 10% from the invoice pdf. I couldn't find it on script. I wanted to know if there is a way to update this or to rewrite the module who handle the GST value.
The attached image  is the print button in sales invoice from Admin area.

[image]

Hope that anyone could experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this using the magento inline translation.

This can be found under your app/locale/en_US or preferred language folder in Mage_Sales.csv or Mage_Tax.csv.

Comment: Hi Sorry, but there is no option there to change the value or covert the value.

Comment: You could translate to a %d instead of %s or %01.2f, take a look at http://php.net/sprintf for the underlaying technique